# Retrieve an object that has a member variable with the longest string length

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-objects

Given a Generic List of objects that contain a member variable that is a string, what is the best way to get the object that contains the string with the longest length?

ie.
assuming val1 is the string I'm comparing:

```
0 : { val1 = "a"   }
1 : { val1 = "aa"  }
2 : { val1 = "aba" }
3 : { val1 = "c"   }
```

what needs to be returned is object 2 because "aba" has the greatest length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I'll try again. You can use the following aggregation:

```
Dim result = elements.Aggregate(Function(a, b) If(a.val1.Length > b.val1.Length, a, b))
```

Comment: No, I used `If` on purpose! Try it, this construct is new to VB 9. `IIf` is now obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an order-by:

```
var x = myStringArray.OrderBy(s => s.Length).Last();
```

Comment: `OrderBy` has the disadvantage of being slower because sorting takes at least O(n logn).

Comment: yes, this is what i initially thought of, this question was asked to me by a co-worker.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim longestLength = elements.Max(Function(el) el.val1.Length)
Dim longest = elements.First(Function(el) el.val1.Length = longestLength)
```